# Is there a benefit to enabling router RIP on my home router?

Tags: home-networking

I'm just curious if this will improve my small home network. What are the cons to using it at home? BTW, I use a WRT54GL with Tomato Firmware.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[RIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_Information_Protocol) is a dynamic routing protocol. Unless you have multiple routers you need to distribute routes to there really isn't any reason to run it. All it will do is put extra traffic on the wire and eat up a few cpu cycles on your router.

Comment: RIP has quite a few known vulnerabilities as well (esp. in older versions), so it's probably best to leave it off

Answer (score 1):

The con to using it is that it will flood your network with updates periodically.  If you only have a single router it is unnecessary.